# Firebase Crashlytics Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable only on release flavor

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I managed to get firebase crashlytics working, problem is, it only works in debug. I don't know what is wrong with release version. I am not doing anything special in build gradle for release version. Here is the error

```
2020-01-16 11:28:06.478 26363-26411/? W/CrashlyticsCore: Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.
2020-01-16 11:28:06.478 26363-26363/? D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
2020-01-16 11:28:06.496 3161-3175/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor/.receiver.CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver
2020-01-16 11:28:06.599 19566-19566/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1531 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:664 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:664 com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor.receiver.CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:54 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3386 
2020-01-16 11:28:06.626 3161-3175/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor/.receiver.CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver
2020-01-16 11:28:06.743 3161-3175/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.sonyericsson.crashmonitor/.receiver.CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver
2020-01-16 11:28:11.674 26741-26741/? I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33
2020-01-16 11:28:11.686 26741-26785/? D/CrashlyticsCore: Found previous crash marker.
2020-01-16 11:28:11.688 26741-26741/? D/CrashlyticsCore: Exception handling initialization successful
2020-01-16 11:28:11.688 26741-26741/? I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
2020-01-16 11:28:11.690 26741-26785/? D/CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID 5E1F91FB02B0-0001-6875-EBC78A642606
2020-01-16 11:28:12.299 26741-26785/? D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file created.
2020-01-16 11:28:12.301 26741-26777/? W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
2020-01-16 11:28:12.302 26741-26785/? D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file removed: true
```

I have been searching the internet, I found some people had the same problem. Tried every solution nothing works. I even have a release and debug folder with google-service.json still did not work. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Did u gout your answer?